# How to solve a large linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming

I have the linear programming problem in $\mathbf x \in\mathbb R^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathbf c^T\mathbf x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf A\mathbf x \leq \mathbf b\end{array}$$

where $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ has the following structure

$$\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A_1\\ \begin{array}{c}\mathbf A_2 &\mathbf 0\end{array}\end{bmatrix}$$

The elements of $\mathbf A_1$ and $\mathbf A_2$ are non-zero, and $m$ and $n$ are very large. Are there any methods to solve the linear programming recursively or solve several small-sized sub-problems?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ask that in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Not in general, but if the problem has some structure there may be hope.  You might look up [Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition)

Comment: Depends on how large is "very large" and what kind of computational resources you have to bear on the problem.  But yes, this forum is not the place for it (and I don't know the state of the art).

Comment: Post on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: The way you write $A$ is confusing. Why not write it as a $2 \times 2$ block matrix in which $A_{22} = O$?

Comment: How large are $m$ and $n$?  thousands, millions, billions?  How dense are the blocks $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$?